# I mistakingly cancelled my android software system update I can get it back again and what are the procedures

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 4g, touch, htc-mytouch

I mistakingly cancelledy android system update 
Please can any one teach me the procedure of updat my android system software ?

There is no select option from the main men

> about 
>   phone
>   network 
>   batery etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get it back by going to . Settings >> About phone >> System Update. There you will see updates of your phone that are available. You can start the updates of your system from there and it work back again.